# Trac 1.0 Apache 2.x integration

Tags: python, apache, trac

I have successfully installed trac 1.0 . It is running fine when in standalone mode .
I am getting the following error after doing the integration with Apache mod_wsgi

```
mod_wsgi (pid=23895): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/cgi-bin/trac_pcbb.trac.wsgi'.
[Tue Sep 30 19:40:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.10.218] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Sep 30 19:40:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.10.218]   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/trac_pcbb.trac.wsgi", line 30, in application
[Tue Sep 30 19:40:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.10.218]     from trac.web.main import dispatch_request
[Tue Sep 30 19:40:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.10.218] ImportError: No module named trac.web.main
```

Comment: Don't put WSGI code in /cgi-bin.

Comment: You might want to give readers of you question a hint on the information used for you setup, maybe a specific guide or distribution-specific set of instructions.